# Don't allow an user to delete a file owned by the user

Tags: permissions

I have an FTP server with an user called "thomas". Every file in that FTP folder is owned by "thomas". There is a file called "screenlog.0" and I don't want it to be deleted by "thomas". How to revoke "thomas"'s access to delete that file, but he must also be able to read it.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood question correctly, I think you should try command:

> chmod u-w screenlog.0